# PHP Dynamic Webpage

Tags: php, html

I'm attempting to create a dynamic website where certain site content loads in to index.php's body.
I currently have the site divided in to 3 sections: Header, Body, and Footer where each of these sections are dynamically separate from each other.

```
<?php
     if(!file_exists('content/header.php'))
     {
          die('Sorry we are experiencing technical difficulties. Please come back later.');
     }
     else
          include('content/header.php');
?>
<?php
    include('content/body.php'); 
?>
<?php    
    include('content/footer.html'); 
?>
```

Now what I'm hoping to do is have certain page content load in to body.php if lets say I click on a hyperlink that says "register" so that a user my register them selves to the site, register.php will load its contents in to body.php.

I've tried searching around but I think I'm asking the wrong questions in Google search so I figured I'd explain my self here and hopefully someone would guide me in the right direction, Thank you for your time.

Comment: The question you need to ask "PHP Template Engine Sample".

Comment: This is a rather prehistorical approach : )) Check how modern frameworks like Symfony or Laravel work, and say goodby to all the `include` mess.

Comment: lol, ok I will check out Symfony or Laravel. Honestly I feel like I'm always trying to catch up to what's new in web development and apparently this is still true in this case. Thanks much to everyone that posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it so the user doesn't get redirected look at AJAX.

Otherwise you could have the register redirect to `index.php?page=register` and your code be

```
<?php
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? 'body' : someSanitizingFunction($_GET['page']);
    include('content/'.$page.'.php'); 
?>
```

That's obviously a unsecure implementation but you'll get the idea from it.

You should also look at a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), that may be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

To create simple layouts in PHP you can write pages like **about.php, contact.php and register.php**, then
you can put this code in your **body.php**

```
  $whitelist = array("about", "register", "contact");
  if(in_array($_GET['page'], $whitelist)) {
    include($_GET['page'].".php");
  } else {
     include("error404.php");
  }
```

Your url should be like **index.php?page=register**.

I also recommend to have a look in MVC frameworks with [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [TemplatePower](http://templatepower.codocad.com/). It is a good way to sort with layouts.